# WPF: Dynamically building tree

Tags: wpf

I want to build a dynamic tree by calling the roots and childs from the methods below. 
I have a TransactionTypeViewModel which has 3 methods

```
tranViewModel.GetWSMethodName()
tranViewModel.GetAllRequest()
tranViewModel.GetAllResponse()
```

I have this list of string where i need to loop thru the methods and add the items to my string list below:
The strings will be used to display the root and child of the tree.

```
List<String> wsMethodNameList = new List<String>();   // root of tree  from tranViewModel.GetWSMethodName()
List<String> requestXmlList = new List<String>();      // child1  tranViewModel.GetAllRequest()
List<String> responseXmlList = new List<String>();     // child2  tranViewModel.GetAllResponse()
```

Once I get the list of strings from each methods i want to build my tree.

```
List<TreeViewModel> nodes = getAllTreeNodesFromModel();
        var request = new TreeViewModel();
        var response = new TreeViewModel();
        var parent = new TreeViewModel();

        List<TreeViewModel> requestNodes = new List<TreeViewModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < requestXmlList.Count; i++)
        {
           // requestNodes = new List<TreeViewModel>();
            request = new TreeViewModel { Value = requestXmlList[i] };
            //requestNodes.Add(request);
            request.Children = nodes;
        }


        List<TreeViewModel> responseNodes = new List<TreeViewModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < responseXmlList.Count; i++)
        {
           // responseNodes = new List<TreeViewModel>();
            response = new TreeViewModel { Value = responseXmlList[i] };
            // responseNodes.Add(response);
            response.Children = nodes;
        }

        List<TreeViewModel> parentNode = new List<TreeViewModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < wsMethodNameList.Count; i++)
        {

           // parentNode = new List<TreeViewModel>();
            parent = new TreeViewModel { Value = wsMethodNameList[i] };
          //  parentNode.Add(parent);
            parent.Children.Add(request);
            parent.Children.Add(response);

        }

        return new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> { parent };
```

After I excute this all I get is duplicated treeview. I couldn't find an easier way to solve this. Can someone help me understand?

Comment: You're doing some very odd things with your `request` and `response` variables, reassigning them multiple times and, as far as I can tell at a quick look, setting up a situation where `response.Children` contains `response`. It doesn't look to me like you've thought enough about what data structure you're actually building, and what steps you need to take to transform from what you've got to what you want. Try 'running' the code step by step in your head and see what happens. Note: there is almost certainly an easier way to do this using LINQ, but you have to learn LINQ first.

Comment: thanks Matthew I know i am doing it wrong some place but i just couldn't put my finger on it.. about LINQ I am very new to that.

Comment: I found out what my problem is I will post a solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out what the issue is. I was creating loops for each lists I have. Here is how I cleaned it:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < wsMethodNameList.Count; i++)
        {
            var child = new TreeViewModel { Value = wsMethodNameList[i] };
            parent.Children.Add(child);

            var requestChild = new TreeViewModel { Value = requestXmlList[i] };

            requestChild.Children = nodes;
            child.Children.Add(requestChild);


            var responseChild = new TreeViewModel { Value = responseXmlList[i] };

            responseChild.Children = nodes;
            child.Children.Add(responseChild);               

        }

        return new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> { parent };
```